# Provide serverside rendered template for Dojo widget

Tags: dojo, serverside-javascript

is there a way in Dojo template based widgets to use server side rendered template instead of static *.html file?
In documentation they do sth like:

- add dependency on  `"dojo/text!./templates/AuthorWidget.html"` - it gives string which is parsed later on to attach all events, instantiate inner widgets etc.
- string output from this dependency is substituted to `templateString` property

I was trying to just send xhr request to URL which would provide serverside rendered template (so I could easier substitute some values instead of using client side JavaScript for that)
I'm getting correct html template and I assign it to `templateString` property but in widget I see only "undefined",

Comment: Have you tried parsing the html template that you are getting from the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can just give the `dojo/text!` plugin a fully-qualified URL to your server-rendered template, and it will get requested when the widget gets `require`d:

```
define('mine/MyWidget', [
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dijit/_WidgetBase',
    'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
    'dojo/text!https://...',
], function () { ... }
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rebolyte/k9tz3fn8/).

Comment: Good answer, I am adding here link to related documentation for reference: https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/templated/